# how to remove special characters using sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I would like to find out how to use sed to ONLY remove the space AND the bizarre characters from the following echo command:

```
echo -e "A \xd8\xa8"
```

So I tried:

```
echo -e "A \xd8\xa8" | sed -r "s/[^[:print:]]//g"
```

but doesn't remove anything,

```
echo -e "A \xd8\xa8" | sed -r "s/[^[:alnum:]]//g"
```

only removes the space

```
echo -e "A \xd8\xa8" | sed -r "s/[^[:alpha:]]//g"
```

(same result),

```
echo -e "A \xd8\xa8" | sed -r "s/[^[:ascii:]]//g"
```

returns an error (invalid character class name), and

```
echo -e "A \xd8\xa8" | sed -r "s/[^\w ]//g"
```

removes everything...

Expected result: "A"

Any ideas ?

thanks!

Comment: I think your question could do with some rewording. You say you want to remove "the space and the bizarre characters", but you work with character classes -- somewhat randomly it seems. What is the exact criteria by which you want to exclude certain characters? Because one man's "bizarre character" is another man's Ø or Ř or и, all of them perfectly good characters in many locales...

Comment: The char is *0628 ARABIC LETTER BEH*. Actually, you may remove it the same way you added it, `sed -r "s/\xd8\xa8//g"`

Comment: it's this particular character that I want to remove, and yes, it is arabic

Comment: ...and thus printing, alphanumeric, and alphabetic, so it's not very surprising that `sed` doesn't remove it...

Comment: @Matt I would not call Arabic letters bizzare. Let's precise: do you want to remove all Arabic chars from a string? Or all non-ASCII chars? Or all non-ASCII letters? Note `[:ascii:]` is an extended POSIX character class that is supported by Perl, e.g.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's just that BASH is unable to print it correctly in the shell, therefore I was calling that character bizarre... :)

Comment: Try `perl -pe 's/\P{ASCII}//g'` to remove all non-ASCII chars. Or, all non-ASCII letters: `perl -CIOED -pe 's/(?![A-Za-z])\p{L}//g'`

Comment: ...using sed please

Comment: So, all non-ASCII symbols? What is your environment?

Comment: my environment, windows subsystem for linux :) on GNU sed 4.2.2

Comment: I also tested it on version 4.4, with same results.
So I guess removing these non-ASCII characters is a tough question...

Comment: Aside: I see the question, the answers and some of the comments using double quotes (`"`) around the sed scripts - that opens up the script to the shell for interpretation before sed even sees it so don't do that unless you have a specific purpose in mind like expanding a shell variable. By default, always use single quotes (`'`) around strings and scripts in shell to avoid problems when the shell interprets something you didn't intend it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `sed` to **not** consider e.g. Arabic characters to be alphabetic (which they are), you need to set a locale that does not consider them thus.

The "C" locale only considers the basic character set, i.e. only `[A-Za-z]` are alphabetic. I am assuming what you want is to delete everything that's not a character from that range (your question is fuzzy about what you really want):

```
echo -e "A \xd8\xa8" | LC_CTYPE=C sed -r "s/[^[:alpha:]]//g" | hexdump -C
```

Output:

```
00000000  41 0a
00000002
```

Comment: sounds good, but a bit tricky to have to change an external variable to get the job done..

Comment: @Matt: If you use it "inline" as I show here, without "export", it is changed only for the subshell executing the `sed`, with no impact on the calling environment. And the LC_ / LANG environment variables _are_ the way to set the locale. It might look "tricky" to you but what you want *is* a different locale.

Answer (score 2):

Raw text:

```
$ echo -e 'A \xd8\xa8' | od -c
0000000   A     330 250  \n
0000005
```

Remove non-ascii chars:

```
$ echo -e 'A \xd8\xa8' | sed 's/[^\x00-\x7F]//g' | od -c
0000000   A      \n
0000003
```

Remove spaces:

```
$ echo -e 'A \xd8\xa8' | sed 's/[[:space:]]//g' | od -c
0000000   A 330 250  \n
0000004
```

Remove non-ascii chars and spaces:

```
$ echo -e 'A \xd8\xa8' | sed 's/[^\x00-\x7F]//g; s/[[:space:]]//g' | od -c
0000000   A  \n
0000002

$ echo -e 'A \xd8\xa8' | sed -E 's/[^\x00-\x7F]|[[:space:]]//g' | od -c
0000000   A  \n
0000002
```

Comment: $ echo -e 'A \xd8\xa8' | sed 's/[^\x00-\x7F]//g' | od -c
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: Invalid collation character
0000000
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.4

Comment: I'm on the same version. Try setting your locale to C (`... | LC_ALL=C sed '...'`) as a quick google shows people reporting that error in some locales and recommending using the C locale to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
$ echo -e "A \xd8\xa8 ña ñe ño áÄãç " | sed -r "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g"
Aaeo
```

An alternative would be to print all ASCII range (but the space character and control characters):

```
$ echo -e "A \xd8\xa8 ña ñe ño áÄãç " | sed -r "s/[^\x21-\x7F]//g"
Aaeo
```

Comment: still doesn't work in version 4.2.2...
Or maybe ti's the windows subsystem for linux which is buggy...

Comment: Just for reference: I used cygwin and sed version is 4.4

Comment: Just tested it with the arabic character in version 4.4, and still doesn't work

Comment: @Matt What's the output you get with those 2 commands? Does DevSolar's answer work for you?

Comment: it works for the first case (which is really explicit), but not the seconde one.
Its output is an empty string.